# Automatic plugin updates not working

Tags: plugins, wp-cron

I have a must use plugin I have made for a client and in it I have the following lines:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' ); // Update plugins automatically
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' ); // Update themes automatically
add_filter( 'auto_update_core', '__return_true' ); // Update core automatically
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' ); // Don't send email for automatic core updates
```

However there is a plugin that shows an update available that isn't updating right now.

I disabled WP_CRON in wp-config.php and use this in my crontab as root:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null "http://xxxxxx.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron"
```

Is there a problem with my code or something else?

Comment: This looks in line with documentation. Are you sure your cron changes work? Does it work if you go back to regular WP Cron execution?

Comment: @Rarst cron works because updraft backups are working fine (they require cron jobs)

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Theme updates are also not working.

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using the "Background Update Tester" plugin and all tests for automatic updates pass, still no updates are executed. Also checked cron events wp_update_plugins and wp_update_themes, all in place. Manually triggering wp_update_plugins with WP-CLI doesn't work either. No errors on the console and no errors in debug.log.